# Google Cloud Run returning Server Unavailable Occasionally

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run, google-container-builder

I am running a Flask app at https://recycler-mvdcj7favq-uc.a.run.app/ on Google Cloud Run and occasionally I get 503 server unavailable while refreshing a few times seems to load the page. Also, sometimes a few static files are missing. Regarding the static files, it might be because I am getting Flask to retrieve the static files but I am confused on why I am constantly getting server unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue, I turned off load balancing and it now doesn't return server unavailable.

Comment: how did you turn off load balancing? just 1 request per container?

Comment: I had load balancing set up under network services but deleting it seemed to fix the issue. @Geshan

Comment: Not sure of the network services probably its on anthos but as I access the above URL more than 50% of the time I get 503 Service Unavailable - even if it loads some css or image is hitting 503 again.

Comment: @Geshan Sorry for the confusion, it worked while it was still up but I shut it down due to billing reasons.